# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation hangs

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2

On a freshly installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 I am installing SQL Server 2008 R2.

After configuring setup, install starts, but then it will hang on: 
Install_sqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_Action: InstallFiles. Copying new files.

What happens here? Why does the installation hang?

Answer (score 1):

As documented, SQL 2008 R2 requires at least .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 - the Windows Server-provided .Net 4.0 **client profile** is not sufficient.

Make sure you have installed the full framework, 3.5 SP1 or higher.

Comment: Dang. And I read the message "needs .net and install thingies" at the start as "am going to install them if you click ok now".

Comment: It is at times like these that you are reminded that SQL Server is entirely its own product, and acts differently than most other Microsoft swag.

Comment: Strange. .Net 3.5.1 already was installed as feature.

Comment: Can you include the relevant bits from the install summary file ?

Comment: Am working on it.

Comment: Long after canceling the setup it reported an timeout error while waiting for "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Users\sys-admin\AppData\Local\Temp\1\3i5ioqvl.cmdline". Is that due to me canceling setup?

Comment: Nyaaarrgrg, it seems my dvd has read errors :( #Damn

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.  I had to verify .Net 3.5.1 was installed then Uninstall all Sql(Express) related programs and reboot.  Afterward, Re-install succeeded.  [it repeatedly failed until i uninstall Sql(Express)].